# MYSQL Replace array of strings with a randomly chosen array of strings

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `users` table with a `user_email` field. I'd like to replace all user emails that match:

- *@a.com
- *@b.com
- *@c.com

With a randomly chosen string from

- d.com
- e.com
- f.com
- g.com

**Example:**

Before:

```
--------------------------------------
|user_name | user_email | user_phone |
--------------------------------------
| greg     | greg@a.com | 12345      |
--------------------------------------
| harry    | harr@b.com | 12345      |
--------------------------------------
| mary     | mary@c.com | 12345      |
--------------------------------------
| john     | john@x.com | 12345      |
--------------------------------------
| fred     | fred@y.com | 12345      |
--------------------------------------
| alfred   | al@a.com   | 12345      |
--------------------------------------
```

After (Replace all "a.com", "b.com", "c.com" occurrences with a randomly chosen one from ["d.com", "e.com", "f.com", "g.com"]:

```
--------------------------------------
|user_name | user_email | user_phone |
--------------------------------------
| greg     | greg@e.com | 12345      |
--------------------------------------
| harry    | harr@e.com | 12345      |
--------------------------------------
| mary     | mary@f.com | 12345      |
--------------------------------------
| john     | john@x.com | 12345      |
--------------------------------------
| fred     | fred@y.com | 12345      |
--------------------------------------
| alfred   | al@d.com   | 12345      |
--------------------------------------
```

John, and Fred remain unchanged. Greg, Harry, Mary, and Alfred get one from ["d.com", "e.com", "f.com", "g.com"] randomly.

Any pointers on how to do this? 
Thank you

Comment: Could you demonstrate exactly what you require as it is unclear what you require

Comment: You can create a temporary table, fill in your data. Then create an UPDATE ... SELECT query, that will change every email with a random record from the temporary table.

Comment: I added an explanation there. I can't create a new table, but it isn't a requirement that I use only 1 query.

Comment: the randomly chosen domain names are just a few, or can be a lot of records?

Comment: They are about 3, and the searched patterns are about 10

Comment: i updated my answer, if they are just a few you can use ETL function with rand() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a quick and dirty solution, you could use something like this:

```
UPDATE
  emails
SET
  emails.address = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(emails.address, '@', 1), '@', ELT(1+rand()*3, 'd.com', 'e.com', 'f.com', 'g.com'))
WHERE
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(address, '@', -1) IN ('a.com', 'b.com', 'c.com')
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2df6/1).

Using `SUBSTRING_INDEX(address, '@', -1)` you can get the domain part of the address, and you can check if it is a.com, b.com, c.com, etc.

Then you can update your email address, concatenating the first part of the address `SUBSTRING_INDEX(address, '@', -1)`, the separator @, and a randomly chosen domain using ETL function:

```
ELT(1+rand()*3, 'd.com', 'e.com', 'f.com', 'g.com')
```

where 1+3 is the number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

My first Idea is something like

```
UPDATE user
SET user_email = CASE
           WHEN user_email LIKE '%a.com' THEN (SELECT REPLACE(user_email, 'a.com', 'd.com'))
           ELSE user_email
END
```

or to match multiple domains:

```
UPDATE email
SET user_email = CASE
   WHEN (user_email REGEXP '[a-c].com$') 
   THEN (SELECT CONCAT((SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_email, '@', 1)), 'y.com' ))
   ELSE user_email
END
```

Comment: This works. I could just do that for each a.com, b.com, etc. It isn't random as the question requests, but as I explained in the comments I can't create a temporary table for the job.